# In Ruby, how do I move a block out of a class into it's own file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

As a learning exercise I am making a simplified Rails-like MVC framework.
Here is a simplified version of the flow. The framework and app are combined here.

1) Initiate a new Rack application.

```
# config.ru
require_relative 'config/application.rb'
run Application.new
```

2) Instantiate a Rack request object, then instantiate a new Router class instance, passing the request object, and call the resolve method.

```
# config/application.rb
require_relative '../lib/router.rb'
class Application
  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    Router.new(request).resolve
  end
end
```

3) When the Router instance is created, I am building a @routes variable assigned to a hash of the application's routes and their corresponding controller and action. Like Rails this is a block. The draw and match methods are defined in this same Router class. Draw runs the block and the match method adds each route to the @routes hash. This works fine.

```
# lib/router.rb
class Router
  attr_reader :request, :routes

  def initialize(request)
    @request = request
    @routes = {}
    draw do
      match "/", "pages#home"
      match "/contact", "pages#contact"
      match "/about", "pages#about"
    end
  end

  def draw(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  def match(url, controller_action)
    @routes["#{url}"] = controller_action
  end
  # more code... def resolve, etc.
end
```

Like Rails I want the draw block in it's own file so the routes can be set in the app's config/routes.rb file and manipulated in the framework's lib/router.rb file. How do I do this? Everything I've tried throws errors.

Comment: What errors are you getting? They're usually informative.

Comment: One thing I note here is you're creating a new router for every request. You probably want a persistent one that's used repeatedly.

Comment: In responding to your question I tried a bunch of different ways, so I just tried a new way to give the error message but this time it actually worked. If I put the block inside a method and put it in a separate folder, require the folder, and call the method in initialize it works. Pretty simple.

Comment: But your point about creating the new routes hash for each request is valid. But each request is to a different url so it has to go through the route matching each time. Persisting the @routes variable would be good but I don't think there's any way to do it without saving it to a session or cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it's not so pretty like Rails you can try to adjust it to your case:

File **routes.rb**:

```
class Routes                                                                                                            
  def self.routes                                                                                                       
    Proc.new do                                                                                                         
      match 'url', 'foo#bar'                                                                                            
      match 'url2', 'foo#baz'                                                                                           
    end                                                                                                                 
  end                                                                                                                   
end
```

File **router.rb**:

```
require_relative './routes'                                                                                             

class Router                                                                                                            
  attr_reader :routes                                                                                                   

  def initialize                                                                                                        
    @routes = {}                                                                                                        

    draw Routes.routes                                                                                                  
  end                                                                                                                   

  def draw(block)                                                                                                       
    instance_eval(&block)                                                                                               
  end                                                                                                                   

  def match(url, handler)                                                                                               
    @routes[url] = handler                                                                                              
  end                                                                                                                   
end
```

So you can have defined in a separated file routes:

```
p Router.new.routes # => {"url"=>"foo#bar", "url2"=>"foo#baz"}
```